# Creating Wix Bundle UI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn, wix3.10

I have managed to use Wix Bundle to bundle all my prerequisies and fold them into one single installer exe.
(I have 4 prerequisites and one main software)
This single installer exe uses the basic UI provided by the toolset, the one obtained by specifying

However, now I am trying to acheive is a good user experience while installing this bundle.

Ideally, on clicking the single installer exe,

```
- the user should be presented with the welcome dialog
- followed by the EULA dialog
- followed by the list of prerequisites which the installer is gonna install
- size of the install along with the option to change the install path (ideally different path for different software, for e.g if i am gonna install sql server and my software, i would like the user to ask two install path one for each)
- Installation progress
- at the end a finshed dialog
```

Can you guys let me know how to acheive all this?

Comment: Even I'm eager to see the answer. As I'm a NSIS installer fan and recently have plans in mind that I should also learn the Windows Installer as well as Wix.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for - but very nice theme for a WiX bundle: http://classicwixburntheme.codeplex.com/

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen: Thank you for the link. Does you comment imply that I need to create "theme for Wix bundle" to achieve what I want?

Comment: @phoenix - a theme can help improving the user experience